# Rolling intercept estimation for a data panel

Tags: regression, least-squares, panel-data

I am working with a panel containing $T$ **daily** observations (one for each $t = 1, 2, ..., T$) for each element $i$ ($i = 1, 2, ..., N$) of the dependent variable $y$. The panel is unbalanced because some of the $y_{it}$ were not observed for all days. Specifically, $y_{it}$ would be the return of company $i$ on day $t$.

I am interested in calculating, for each element $i$ and for each **month** $t'$ ($t' = 1, 2, ..., T'$), the intercept coefficient from a regression of the $y_{it}$ on a common factor $x_t$ (think a market index return). $x_t$ is not specific to any $i$ element (because the market index is unique), but can of course be expressed in the form $X_{it}$ by simply replicating its values on each day for each element $i$ in the sample.

I have though of two possible procedures to achieve my objective:

1. Run the following time series regression for each $i$ ($i = 1, 2, ..., N$) and each month $t'$ ($t' = 1, 2, ..., T'$) in the sample: $y_{it} = \alpha_i + b_ix_t + u_{it}$. This should result in a series of $T'$ $\alpha_i$ values, one for each element $i$ and each month $t'$.
2. Alternatively, run a fixed-effects panel regression at each month $t'$: $Y_{it} = \beta X_{it} + \alpha_i + u_{it}$, where $\alpha_i$ would be the time-invariant (within each month $t'$) individual effect (for each $i$-th individual firm).

First, are the two procedures correctly defined? Second, how can I determine which of the two is more appropriate for my analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third alternative would be to consider one single equation with $\alpha_{i,t'}$:
$Y_{i,t}=\beta X_{i,t}+\alpha_{i,t'}+u_{i,t}$

With just your methods 1- or 2-, there would be a question of how the constants are defined between regressions.

Comment: I see what you mean and I agree it would be optimal to estimate everything at once, but how would you do it in practice? What I mean is: if you run a fixed effects regression using daily data over the entire period you would get a single $\alpha_i$ for each firm $i$ over the entire period. How can you actually estimate a different $\alpha_{i,t'}$ for each firm $i$ and at each month $t'$?

Comment: You create manually the corresponding dummies and make a normal regression.

Comment: I will try doing the above and check the result. What are the main advantages of using your procedure instead of the two I proposed above? I can see it is intuitively better to run a single regression, but what do you exactly mean with "how the constants are defined between regressions"?

Comment: In a fixed effect regression, the fixed effects are defined to a constant. For instance, the fixed effect for the fort individual is 0. Or (in stata), the sum of all fixed effects is zero. Hence, you would choose as many conventions as there are regressions...

Comment: Does this also hold for a normal time series regression such as (1)? Based on what you say I understand why I should not use (2) but I am unsure why I shouldn't use procedure (1).

Comment: I would dis-advice it also.. In 2/, you could ensure that for instance i=1 is the reference guy and the corresponding fixed effect is 0. This imposes T' "initial conditions". In (1), you would similarly impose NT' "initial conditions", instead of only 1 "initial condition", as in my suggestion